# routine or routinely should be used in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

a business is operating **routinely.**

Is the use of *routinely* as an adverb in that sentence appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

**routinely** is the correct word here. It answers the question **how?** or **in what way?** and is an adverb whilst **routine** is mostly a noun but can also be an adjective.

Comment: +1.  **Routine** can also be an adjective.

Comment: ... and a [verb](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/routine)